How to Align Text below QR code Scanner Overlay in Flutter?
I have implemented QR Code Scanner for my app and I want to align text dynamically below the Overlay of QR Code Scanner. I have used qr_code_scanner package. I have tried it to make in Stack widget and wrap Text with Align like this:
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    _buildQRView(context), //QR Code Scanner Overlay
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.4),
      child: Text(
        "Scan QR Code",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),

For my device I gave static alignment: AlignmentIt(0.0, 0.4) and works perfectly fine in my device but when I try to run in another devices it will goes above the Overlay or align according to different device's size. I want to make it dynamic means if device size is anything then It would be stick to below the QR Code Scanner's Overlay.
Here's my device image:


Instead of Stack() you can use a Column() with cross and main axis alignment "center" and also wrap the Column() with Center(). And just add a SizedBox() with height or 10/20/30 in between your QrCode() and Text().

try this:
   Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        _buildQRView(context), //QR Code Scanner Overlay
        const Text(
          "Scan QR Code",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),


Try to use Positioned widget and align the widget using left, right, top and bottom parameters.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
